# Access to IAM users for EC2 Instance Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

How can I restrict the user from connecting to my Linux instance using EC2 Instance Connect?

I have tried to set policy and attach users to connect for my newly created Amazon Linux 2 instance using EC2 Instance Connect:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:111122223333:instance/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111122223333:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner": "Bob"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But, it doesn't seem to work.

Presently the newly created instance can be accessed by everyone.

So, I want to set a policy to that particular instance that only the specified IAM users can access it and others cannot.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You are attaching the given IAM policy to a user aren't you? Then you can restrict access to the attached user only. If you want to exclude all users (which are already granted access), you must use another IAM construct such as SCPs (if you use AWS organizations).

Answer (score 5):

Your `Deny` policy is overriding your `Allow` policy.

Your statements are saying:

- **Do not allow** this user to use EC2 Instance Connect on any instance
- **Allow** this user to use EC2 Instance Connect on any instance with the given tag

However, Deny always beats Allow.

You could simply **remove your `Deny` policy**. This would grant permission for EC2 Instance Connect only to the tagged instances (assuming that the user has not also been given permission elsewhere).

Comment: The op is using regions to differentiate between the Allow and the Deny...one is eu-west-1, the other us-east-1.